# How to log queries with bounded paramenters in Sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

I am using sequelize (version 5.3.5) to connect to a postgre database and have configured the logging to use `console.log`, but whenever a query with bounded parameters appears, I am unable to see which parameters are being bound.

The configuration is very standard.

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
let db = new Sequelize (
    "database", "username", "password",
    {
        dialect: 'postgres',
        logging: console.log
    }
);
```

Taking for example this log of an INSERT operation (inside a transaction):

```
Executing (a7ed97b4-66a2-43a2-b4c5-eaa067e7ec28): INSERT INTO "Entities" ("id","type","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4) RETURNING *;
```

Is there a way to make sequelize show me what values are being mapped to `$1` .. `$6`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I revisited this after a while, and with sequelize at version `5.19.0` I found that there is a property where all the bound values are stored.

Going back to it:

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
let db = new Sequelize (
    "database", "username", "password",
    {
        dialect: 'postgres',
        logging: customLogger
    }
);


function customLogger ( queryString, queryObject ) {
    console.log( queryString )      // outputs a string
    console.log( queryObject.bind ) // outputs an array
}
```

Comment: basically in your code i have tested it prints the complete object of the model that are involved in query by the Variable `queryObject.bind`. Instead if somebody just want to see the bind variable just need to add `logQueryParameters: true` below the  logging line in sequelize object creation as defined in the first answer of this thread.

Answer (score 7):

**`logQueryParameters: true`**

We now have this option which does it, usage:

```
  sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: 'tmp.sqlite',
    logQueryParameters: true,
  })
```

It outputs something like:

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `IntegerNames` 
(`id`,`value`,`name`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (NULL,$1,$2,$3,$4); 
{"$1":2,"$2":"two","$3":"2022-02-02 10:37:21.618 +00:00","$4":"2022-02-02 10:37:21.618 +00:00"}
```

Full example:

main.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const assert = require('assert')
const path = require('path')
const { DataTypes, Sequelize } = require('sequelize')
let sequelize
if (process.argv[2] === 'p') {
  sequelize = new Sequelize('tmp', undefined, undefined, {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    host: '/var/run/postgresql',
    logQueryParameters: true,
  })
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: 'tmp.sqlite',
    logQueryParameters: true,
  })
}
;(async () => {
const IntegerNames = sequelize.define('IntegerNames', {
  value: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER },
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
});
await IntegerNames.sync({ force: true })
async function reset() {
  await sequelize.truncate({ cascade: true })
  await IntegerNames.create({ value: 2, name: 'two' })
  await IntegerNames.create({ value: 3, name: 'three' })
  await IntegerNames.create({ value: 5, name: 'five' })
}
await reset()
let rows
rows = await IntegerNames.findAll()
assert.strictEqual(rows[0].id, 1)
assert.strictEqual(rows[0].name, 'two')
assert.strictEqual(rows[0].value, 2)
assert.strictEqual(rows[1].id, 2)
assert.strictEqual(rows[1].name, 'three')
assert.strictEqual(rows[1].value, 3)
assert.strictEqual(rows[2].id, 3)
assert.strictEqual(rows[2].name, 'five')
assert.strictEqual(rows[2].value, 5)
assert.strictEqual(rows.length, 3)
})().finally(() => { return sequelize.close() })
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "tmp",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "pg": "8.5.1",
    "pg-hstore": "2.3.3",
    "sequelize": "6.14.0",
    "sqlite3": "5.0.2"
  }
}
```

output:

```
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `IntegerNames`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `IntegerNames` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `value` INTEGER, `name` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL);
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_LIST(`IntegerNames`)
Executing (default): DELETE FROM `IntegerNames`
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `IntegerNames` (`id`,`value`,`name`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (NULL,$1,$2,$3,$4); {"$1":2,"$2":"two","$3":"2022-02-02 10:38:54.369 +00:00","$4":"2022-02-02 10:38:54.369 +00:00"}
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `IntegerNames` (`id`,`value`,`name`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (NULL,$1,$2,$3,$4); {"$1":3,"$2":"three","$3":"2022-02-02 10:38:54.379 +00:00","$4":"2022-02-02 10:38:54.379 +00:00"}
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `IntegerNames` (`id`,`value`,`name`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (NULL,$1,$2,$3,$4); {"$1":5,"$2":"five","$3":"2022-02-02 10:38:54.385 +00:00","$4":"2022-02-02 10:38:54.385 +00:00"}
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `value`, `name`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `IntegerNames` AS `IntegerNames`;
```

Tested PostgreSQL 13.5.

I couldn't use it when I wanted to indent my queries though: [How to indent/pretty print logged queries in sequelize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70948142/how-to-indent-logged-queries-in-sequelize/70948143#70948143) so I just used the `queryObject.bind` mentioned by Rafael in that case.