# sequelize: How to log raw query

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I use `sequelize` with `postgresql` and logger `winston`. Here is my code:

```
logging: e => logger('sequelize').info(e)
```

this logs the result like this:

```
INSERT INTO "test" ("id","aa","bb","cc") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3) RETURNING *; // I don't want this
```

how to change so that the output will like this?

```
INSERT INTO "test" ("id","aa","bb","cc") VALUES (DEFAULT,"AA","BB","CC") RETURNING *; // I want this
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55715724/how-to-log-queries-with-bounded-paramenters-in-sequelize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option for this in the Sequelize constructor:

`logQueryParameters : true`

It does work, but you might have to play around with it to get the log formatted the way you want.  Unfortunately, I can't find any good examples.  There was [a recent bug fix](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11151) of this feature, so make sure your package is current.

Comment: It really should be true by default! The format will be like this `INSERT INTO "test" ("id","aa","bb","cc") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3) RETURNING *; "AA", "BB", "CC"`